# Playing sound on a button click

Tags: javascript, html5

I am new to javascript and want to make sure I am on the right track when playing a sound. Is there anything I should not be doing better or not be doing at all. Below is a simple function.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function playSound(soundfile) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1) {
      document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = "<embed src=\"" + soundfile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" type=\"application/x-mplayer2\" />";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = "<embed src=\"" + soundfile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="dummy"></span>

  <a href="#" onclick="playSound('doorbell.wav');">Click here to hear a sound</a>
</body>
```

I am not sure whether I should be using the audio tag or not. I appreciate any feedback

Comment: Why do you use [`embed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element) instead of [`audio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-audio-element)?

Comment: Consider building the element using something like jQuery instead of doing a concatenation of strings which is hard to read and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't duplicate sections of code! In particular, avoid putting 'execution' code in these simple conditionals, instead use them to build a shared executor:

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
  var type_attr = '';
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1) {
    type_attr = "type=\"application/x-mplayer2\"";
  }
  document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = "<embed src=\"" + soundfile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" " + type_attr + " />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the HTML:

#### `script` element

For JavaScript, [you can](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) simply use `<script>` without the `type` attribute:

> If the language is not that described by "text/javascript", then the `type` attribute must be present

The `language` attribute is obsolete:

> Authors should not specify a `language` attribute on a `script` element.

#### `a` element

I'd say a real button should be used here, not a link:

- `button` element with [`button` type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element): `<button type="button" onclick="…">Click here to hear a sound</button>`
- `input` element with [`button` type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#button-state-%28type=button%29): `<input type="button" onclick="…" value="Click here to hear a sound" />`

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery and then do it like this:

```
<pre>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        var obj = document.createElement("audio"); 
        obj.setAttribute("src", "http://kahimyang.info/resources/click.m... 
        $.get(); 

        $(".playSound").click(function() { 
            obj.play(); 
        }); 
    }); 
    </script> 
</pre>
```

Put this snippet at the bottom of the page after that all anchors with class "playSound" will play a sound. Somewhere in your page your link should look loke below:

```
<pre>
    <a href="#" class="playSound">Play</a> 
</pre>
```

For more details visit this blog:

http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1652/how-to-play-a-sound-when-an-element-is-clicked-in-html-page